# Debugger warning from IPython: frozen modules

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.11

I created a new environment using conda and wanted to add it to jupyter-lab. I got a warning about frozen modules? (shown below)

```
$ ipython kernel install --user --name=testi2 
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Installed kernelspec testi2 in /home/michael/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/testi2
```

All I had installed were ipykernel, ipython, ipywidgets, jupyterlab_widgets, ipympl

Python Version 3.11.0, Conda version 22.11.0

And I used `conda install nodejs -c conda-forge --repodata-fn=repodata.json` to get the latest version of nodejs

I also tried re-installing ipykernel to a previous version (6.20.1 -> 6.19.2)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is just a warning that the debugger cannot debug frozen modules.

> In Python 3.11, the core modules essential for Python startup are “frozen”. ... This reduces the steps in module execution process ... Interpreter startup is now 10-15% faster in Python 3.11. This has a big impact for short-running programs using Python.

— What’s New In Python 3.11 § [Faster Startup](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#faster-startup)

> it's not possible for the debugger to debug frozen modules as the filename is definitely required to hit breakpoints

— https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/213#issuecomment-1058247166

E.g. `os.path.realpath.__code__.co_filename` is now `'<frozen posixpath>'` in Python 3.11.

---

The possible resolutions are mentioned with the warning.

1. If you need to debug those modules, pass `-Xfrozen_modules=off` to `python`:

   ```bash
   # ipython kernel install --user --name=testi2
   python -Xfrozen_modules=off -m ipykernel install --user --name=testi2
   ```

   ```bash
   # jupyter-lab
   python -Xfrozen_modules=off -m jupyterlab
   ```
2. If you just want to suppress the warning, set `PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1`:

   ```bash
   PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 ipython kernel install --user --name=testi2
   ```

   ```bash
   PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 jupyter-lab
   ```

Comment: why would there need to be any debugging of modules when adding a conda virtual environment to jupyter lab?

Comment: There is no need to. The validation is run at import time: ipkernel.py `from .debugger import ...` → `from debugpy.server import ...` → `import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd` → `preimport('pydevd', [..., 'pydevd',])` → `import pydevd_file_utils` → filename validation.

Comment: Related to this: a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76149677/8508004) about where to put `PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 jupyter-lab`. I'm just tagging this with a temporary comment in the hopes those knowledgeable may see the new post. New poster cannot comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem i noticed with this is that when you try to run python on visual studio without without a py extension you're most likely to run into an issue like this
and Finally make sure python path is added to Environment Variable . I have done this and its working fine . I am Using Visual studio.
Path is always found here on Windows
C:\Users\NEW\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311