# Where to put Python configuration code related to IPython "frozen modules" debugger warning?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just used brew on a macintosh to upgrade my setup.  Now, I am getting this "Debugger warning" when I run `jupyter notebook` (other text snipped):

```
[I 09:03:00.955 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.3 is running at: ...
    To access the notebook, ...
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

There's a question about the same error: [Debugger warning from IPython: frozen modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114841/debugger-warning-from-ipython-frozen-modules-python-3-11). I wanted to ask for clarification on [aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75114841#75274358) but I don't have [enough reputation to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) so I'm asking it as a new question.

Based on the previous answer, I suppose I can just ignore the error messages.  But suppose I did want to follow aaron's advice?  He advises that I place the following somewhere:

```bash
PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 jupyter-lab
```

Does that text go in some file somewhere?  What file? Where?
I don't know how to muck about in the bowels of the Python interpreter.

Comment: Ah! I can't comment.  When I try, I get: "You must have at least 50 reputation to comment."  I am too new to stack overflow, so stack overflow won't let me use it.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. It seemed like a good suggestion if the rules weren't blocking you. And you did it right, this is a new question. I was just hoping you could prompt those know more to see this. That's why I said, it may be nice to offer to delete the comment soon.

Comment: It should just be `PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code

```
PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 jupyter-lab
```

should go into your global environment variables. If using a Mac, you should first determine if your shell (bash, zsh, etc.). You can do this with the following command in terminal:

```
echo $SHELL
```

If you see something like '**/bin/bash**' then you're using bash, if you see something like '**/bin/zsh**' then you're using zsh. You'll then want to navigate to your home directory:

```
cd ~
```

Then you will want to open up the corresponding configuration file specific to your shell.

For **zsh**:

```
nano .zshrc
```

For **bash**:

```
nano .bashrc
```

Then type the following line anywhere in the configuration file

```
export PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1
```

The save and exit the file by pressing '**Ctrl + X**', then '**Y**', and finally '**Enter**'

Stop your current Jupyter server, restart your terminal, then try running your sever again.

The steps for Windows are similar, you just need to update the configuration file for whatever you are using to run your terminal commands.