# Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1

Tags: python, python-venv

I wanted to set up a virtial environment name 'tfod', but I got stuck on this step

As soon as I entered the following on the terminal:

```
(tfod) C:\Users\Shubh\Desktop\TFOD\TFODCourse>python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tfod
```

The following error was generated:

```
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Installed kernelspec tfod in C:\Users\Shubh\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\tfod
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugger Warning from ipython: Frozen Modules \[python 3.11\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114841/debugger-warning-from-ipython-frozen-modules-python-3-11)